# jQuery trigger mouseover function when page loads with the mouse over the element

Tags: asp.net, jquery, mouseover, pageload

I have an ASP.NET document, with an Image element within it.
I created a `mouseover` function on this image element and it's working fine.
The question is:
If the mouse is ALREADY over the element when the document loads itself, the `mouseover` function doesn't trigger (I need to `mouseout` and then `mouseover` again in order to trigger it).
Is there any way to check in the `$(document).ready` function if the mouse is already on top of this element? and if yes- trigger the `mouseover` function.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `mousemove` event? You could make it fire only once by setting a flag called movedOver to true, and then setting the flag to false on `mouseleave`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, 
try to use [`$('#elem').load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method.